# 64bit Alternatives for WPF WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Are there any good alternatives to the `WebBrowser` control for WPF which will work in 64 bit builds?

The alternatives I've found to the standard control only work in 32 bit processes.

Ideally this would be a control which does not have airspace issues, and works properly when composed with WPF content.

Comment: If the awesomium team ever gets off their collective posteriors, it's a fairly decent wrapper around the chromium browser...last I checked, however, it was still 32 bit. :(

Comment: @JerKimball Yeah - Chromium/Awesomium would be an ideal option, as the 32bit version is great.  There was a gecko version for a while, but it was 32bit only, too, and doesn't seem to be maintained anymore either.

Comment: You know, I had to do an exploratory spike wrt this a couple months ago; when I get back to my desk I'll dig up my notes.

Comment: These were the browser controls I messed with, even tho we ended up going for awesomium 32-bit: https://code.google.com/p/geckofx/ https://code.google.com/p/open-webkit-sharp/ http://awesomium.com/  =https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XULRunner http://wpfchromium.codeplex.com/

Comment: @JerKimball From what I remember, only the geckofx supported 64bit, and it had some serious issues.

Comment: Yeah, it's a mess out there - the Chromium team still hasn't put out the 64 bit version on windows (although it exists for (U|Li)n(u|i)x), and god help you if you go down the mozilla route - there be dragons there. You *might* be able to create your own wrapper around something like WebKit, but again, only if you enjoy pain.

Comment: @JerKimball For now, I'm just using the built in browser - with the IE compat setup properly in the registry, it's okay (the default behavior is horrible, though)

Comment: I sympathize completely. :) I had to go with a chromium derivative as the webapp we were embedding wasn't playing nicely with IE.

Answer (score 0):

You can always host the WinForms version of `WebBrowser` control in your WPF application using the `WindowsFormsHost` component:D
Like this:
[stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387921/how-to-make-winform-run-on-wpf)

Or you can try this:
[stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552144/embed-firefox-gecko-in-wpf-c)

Comment: Does this satisfy OP's question? "Ideally this would be a control which does not have airspace issues, and works properly when composed with WPF content."